# Two columns from CSV file are not working for if-statement?

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

I am developing a simple application in where it reads the CSV file sent in and produces some results based on the data points in the columns. Data.csv:

```
Something, everything, 6, xy
Something1, everything1, 7, ab
Something2, everything2, 9, pq
```

I open the file as following,

```
FileOpen = opne('../sources/data.csv', 'rU')
FileRead = csv.reader(FileOpen, delimiter = ',')
FileRead.next()

for row in FileRead:
   #This does not work
   if row[0] == 'something' and row[1] == 'something1':
      print row[2]

   #This works
   if row[0] == 'something' and row[3] = 'xy':
      print row[2]
```

The above code does not show anything. But if I used row[0] and row [3] in the if condition, it works well. So the problem is with the column 1, 2. But 0 and 3 columns work fine. Is the file format of CSV wrong? I following microsoft procedure to create csv from excel file.

Comment: `row[0]` is the _column_ its not the row. So `row[0]` is actually "Something", row[1] is "everything" and row[2] is `6` for the first row.

Comment: something1 vs everything1

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jasper is row[0] == 'something' and row[1] == 'everything' means I want to display 6. But it is not displaying

Comment: You need `row[0] == 'Something' and row[1] == 'everything'` with the capital S

Comment: No, that is not the reason. I tried. I do not know what am i doing wrong...

Comment: if you want to make it case insensitive, you can call lower() on the columns, like ` row[0].lower() == 'something'`

Comment: looks like you are skipping the first row with FileRead.next(). Is that intentional? do you have a header row?

Comment: Yes, first row is the title row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use and naming of `row` is completely correct. The main problem is the white space in your file. If I `print row`, I get

```
['Something', ' everything', ' 6']
               ^              ^
```

The solution will most likely deal with

> Dialect.skipinitialspace
>
> ```
> When True, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored. The default is False.
> ```

from here https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters

You pass this option in the constructor like this:

```
FileRead = csv.reader(FileOpen, delimiter = ',', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: I think you are right but the documentation does not show how to use Dialect.skipinitialspace . you have any idea how to use it?

Comment: Spot on! Yes, there were spaces.

Comment: Updated the Answer to include the exact usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they were the spaces after all. To remove spaces in Excel, insert a new column near the column with the spaces and user `=TRIM(C1).` Then you can copy paste the data in a new file and create a CSV from that.